# Return items in an array one by one until all items have been returned then start again

Tags: arrays, swift

What I want to do is be able to return items from an array one by one each time a function is called until all of the items in the array have been returned, then start again with the first item.

The code below does exactly what I need but I feel like there is a simpler way to do this, it just feels weird how I did it.

Any improvements to the code below?

```
var fruits = ["Apple","Banana","blue","Orange"] 

func fruit() -> String { 
    let removedFruit = fruits.removeAtIndex(0)
    fruits.insert(removedFruit, atIndex:fruits.count)

    return removedFruit
} 

// the out put here is exactly what I need
// return Apple the first time the fruit function is called
// then return Banana the second time the function is called and so on...
print(fruit()) // Apple
print(fruit()) // Banana
print(fruit()) // Watermelon
print(fruit()) // Orange

// once all of the items in the array have been returned
// start again with the first item
print(fruit()) // Apple
print(fruit()) // Banana
print(fruit()) // Watermelon
print(fruit()) // Orange
```

Comment: Make the array constant and update an *index* for each function call ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mutate the array, it's expensive.

```
class FruitGenerator {
   let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Poop"]
   var nextItemIndex = 0 // holds the index of item to be returned upon the next call to fruit()
   func fruit() -> String {
      let result = fruits[nextItemIndex]
      nextItemIndex = (nextItemIndex + 1) % fruits.count
      return result
   }
}
```

Comment: @ Tamas Zahola - Your example work fine, thanks. Now, I have a question. I'm currently learning OOP and I noticed that you used a class in your example, I know I can extract the code from the class if I wanted to but I'm wondering if it is common to create classes for stuff as simple as the code above in Object Oriented. Again, is it common to create a class for simple stuff? Is this how you would structure your code?

Comment: Depends on the use case. But I certainly wouldn't use a global array anywhere but a Swift Playground. Now, let's say you wanted to use this wrapping array mechanism on different arrays, not just the fruit array. In this case the next logical step would be to pass in the array in an initializer and not have it hardcoded. This way you would encapsulate this wrapping array concept in a nice, testable, self-containing class.

Comment: @ Tamas Zahola - `But I certainly wouldn't use a global array anywhere but a Swift Playground.` If I understand this correctly a good rule of thumb would be to consider creating a new class every time you need to fetch items from arrays, dictionaries etc., to conform to the MVC pattern, am I correct?

Comment: @fs_tigre if you need to keep track of some _state_ (like `nextItemIndex` in this case) it's a good practice to encapsulate it into an object. Though which state variable belong together depends on your problem domain.

Answer (score -2):

Peace of cake (code edited as fully functional):

```
 var fruits = ["Apple","Banana","blue","Orange"]
 var index = 0

 func fruit() -> String {

let ret = fruits[index]
(index  == (fruits.count-1) ? (index=0) : (index=index+1))
return ret
}
```

The idea here is to keep a reference to your current index.
Use of a tertiary operator to check if we are at the end of the array, if so we reset the index otherwise we increment it.
Note that you may have to use parentheses around the operator.

Comment: This doesn't even compile. The fact that someone would upvote this is really unsettling...

Comment: @thibautnoah it also doesn't compile because your line with the ternary operator is syntactically wrong

Comment: You shouldn't use the ternary operator for side effects. Though it's easy to fix: `i = (i == fruit.count - 1) ? 0 : i + 1`

Comment: @thibautnoah better to write pseudocode then, than to write erroneous code

Comment: depends on who is reading, anyway i edited the code, compiling working etc